# Nmap - host seems down

Tags: security, nmap

Today, I started exploring nmap, and first thing I found out that I can scan IP, so I open CMD(Command Line) and write in ->

`nmap -sS` and my IP

click Enter and it says;

> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn

I try that and Enter, but it started to numbering SYN Stealth Scan Timing in percents(%).

I'm wondering what that means **Host seems down**? Did I write wrong code in cmd or what?

I google it, but no results

Comment: That just means the host is not responding to whatever host discovery probes `nmap` was sending. There's a bunch of paragraphs on the topic under the HOST DISCOVERY section of the `nmap` manual...

Comment: are you running a Unix/Linux OS? "cmd" is suspiciously similar to a Windows-based OS.

Comment: I'm running Win7

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. Disable Windows firewall and try again.